# CollectionViewCell makes random things while scrolling

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

After tapping on a cell, my cell will change background to yellow. When its background is yellow, it will come back to a default color.

Everything works fine, but if I start scrolling some cells will change backgroundColor to yellow although it was not selected. Unluckily it has random behaviour.

I changed creating a cell with `alloc init` but now, it throws an error which says:

```
cells must be retrieved by calling -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
```

I use storyboard to manipulate with elements in cell and using them like

```
 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView
                              dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Number Cell"
                              forIndexPath:indexPath];




UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.item + 1];
```

Any suggestions?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView
                                  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Number Cell"
                                  forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)indexPath.item + 1];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];


        if ([cell.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor yellowColor]]) {

            cell.backgroundColor  = [UIColor clearColor];
        } else {    

            cell.backgroundColor  = [UIColor yellowColor];           
        }

}
```

I assume,

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
    didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called whenever I tap to a cell. So, I change a color to yellow when it has clear color and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should happen automatically if you're setting the yellow background color in your cell's `setSelected:` method, assuming you're also setting it back to normal if someone calls `[cell setSelected:NO]`.

If that doesn't work, you can reset the cell's background color after dequeueing it, or in the cell's `prepareForReuse:` method.

Comment: Reusing a cell makes very unpredicted behaviour. I subclassed a cell and used `prepareForReuse` with clear backgroundColor and the effect is that it totally clear all cells. So, I used it with `if (self.selected == YES)` and no results. I want really simple thing - select and deselect cells with background visualisation.

Comment: @vaberer, can you show a minimal example of what you're doing that causes the problem?

Comment: @vaberer As I said in the first part of my answer, it's probably easiest to simply override `setSelected:` in your cell class to set it to yellow if the argument is YES and clear if it's NO. I don't see why you're testing the cell's background first, since it will call the *deselect* method if the user taps an already-selected cell. The collection view will call `setSelected:` for you in prepareForReuse, so you should only have to override `setSelected:` and can remove your implementation of `didSelectCell...`.

Comment: perfect! I just added `self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;` to select and deselect multiple cells and everything works fine.